# CSS animation effect on hovered image is not working

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I’ve created an animation effect in CSS and it works fine on texts. I want to use it on a PNG image I have used as an icon, as well, but it doesn’t work.

```css
.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
}

.logo:hover {
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-box">
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo-white.png">
</div>
```

Comment: its related to dont use transform as an inital css of logo, when you want to change a property in hover, it must be set as inital css, and then in hover you change it, in this case, .logo{animation : none} for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of selecting the hovered `.logo` itself (which moves its position), target the wrapper that doesn’t move (`.logo-box`), then target the `.logo` for animation. Instead of

```css
.logo:hover {
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

use

```css
.logo-box:hover .logo {
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out;
}
```

### Example:

```css
.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
}

.logo-box:hover .logo {
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-box">
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo-white.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to make the logo box bigger, in HTML you have to do that in body and check your image pawn / your css left

```css
.logo-box {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
}

.logo {
  height: 35px;
}

.logo:hover {
  animation: moveInRight 1.5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes moveInRight {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateX(100px);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateX(-10px);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logo-box">
  <img class="logo" src="img/logo-white.png">
</div>
```

Comment: There is no difference between your code and the OP’s code… the rest of the answer isn’t clear either. What do you mean by _“in HTML you have to do that in body and check your image pawn / your css left”_?